# C# フォームの上に乗せたコントロールにもフォームのマウスイベントが走る簡単な方法

Tags: c#, form

お世話になります。

https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/moveform.html

こちらのサイト様にあるような、フォーム上でドラッグしてフォームの移動をさせるコードを
書いています。

このフォーム上にコントロールを追加すると、そのコントロール上ではマウスイベントは発生しません。移動させるには、追加したコントロールにそれぞれMouseDownとMouseMoveを実装し、その中でOnMouseDownやOnMouseMoveをしないといけません。

これはわかっているのですが、いざフォームにコントロールを五つ六つ…と追加していくと、それぞれに上記の処理を追加しなければならず、手間です。コードでコントロールを追加するなら、コードで何とかできますが、VisualStudioのエディタ上で追加していくと、そうもいきません。

作る側として、その程度の手間は当然といえば当然といわれるかもしれませんが、もしできるなら
もっと楽な方法はありませんでしょうか。たとえて言うなら、キーボードの受付を親が管理する
『KeyPreview』のようなものがあるといいなと思うのですが。

よい実装方法などありましたら、ご助力いただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 英語記事とか。[Equivalent of KeyPreview for Mouse events ?](http://computer-programming-forum.com/4-csharp/7d158e77fa8c8cc4.htm) 少し違うこれ。[C#でMouseWheelのフック](https://tocsworld.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/c%E3%81%A7mousewheel%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF/), [SetWindowsHookEx（ローカルフック）...](https://teratail.com/questions/67587), [C# でHookを使うときの注意事項](http://mycsharp.seesaa.net/article/132281109.html) グローバルフックですが。[C#にてマウスとキーボードを操りし者](https://qiita.com/exliko/items/3135e4413a6da067b35d), [Processing... Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991044/winforms-intercepting-mouse-event-on-main-form-first-not-on-controls

に書いている事を流用して機能拡張してみます。

まずは マウスをクリックするとフォームが移動できるように
マウスイベントの処理を書きます。
この状態では ボタン上で マウスクリックするとフォームの移動はできません。

```
this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
this.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
```

```
        bool mousePressed;
        private Point diff;

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mousePressed = true;

                Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                p = PointToScreen(p);
                diff.X = p.X - DesktopLocation.X;
                diff.Y = p.Y - DesktopLocation.Y;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mousePressed && (e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
            {
                Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                p = PointToScreen(p);
                p.X -= diff.X;
                p.Y -= diff.Y;
                DesktopLocation = p;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePressed = false;
        }
```

次に 上記リンク先の記事を参考に
フォーム上のコントロールのイベントを 転送する設定をします。

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
   control.MouseMove += RedirectMouseMove;
   control.MouseDown += RedirectMouseDown;
}
```

```
        private void RedirectMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            Point screenPoint = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            Point formPoint = PointToClient(screenPoint);
            MouseEventArgs args = new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks,
                formPoint.X, formPoint.Y, e.Delta);

            OnMouseDown(args);
        }

        private void RedirectMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Control control = (Control)sender;
            Point screenPoint = control.PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            Point formPoint = PointToClient(screenPoint);
            MouseEventArgs args = new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks,
                formPoint.X, formPoint.Y, e.Delta);
            OnMouseMove(args);
        }
```

ちょっと、ボタンの色が変わるのが気になりますけど、ボタンの上でマウスクリックしても
ちゃんとフォームが移動できるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速試してみたいと思います。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。